# wrap n number of div in one parent using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have list of html element which has been generated by javascript. Now Every 4 (could be different) should have one parent. The problem is how do we close the div after 4th element.

Here's a snippet (or [here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9n971jwr/1/)):

```js
var x = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"]
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if (i % 3 === 0) {
    html += '<div class="parent">';
  }
  html += '<div class="child">' + x[i] + '</div>'

  if (i % 3 !== 0 || i === (x.length - 1)) {
    html += '</div>';
  }

}

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = html
```

```css
.child{ margin: 10px; background: green; float: left; padding: 20px}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Please use Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) for runnable examples, so they're completely on-site. I've updated your question for you.

Comment: did you try putting `i%3 === 3`instead of `i%3 !== 0` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of starting with `i=0` in the for loop start with `i=1` and end with `i <= x.length`. With this in place the logic should be straight forward.

Here is the code sample

```js
var x = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"]
var html = '';

for (var i = 1; i <= x.length; i++) {
  if (i % 4 === 1) // if remainder is 1 it means the 1st element of the block, So open new parent
    html += '<div class="parent">';

  html += '<div class="child">' + x[i - 1] + '</div>'

  if (i % 4 === 0 || i === x.length) // if remainder is 0 then we have completed 4 elements so close the parent
    html += '</div>';
}

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = html
```

```css
.child {background: yellow;padding: 20px;display: block; flex: 1;}
.parent {border: 2px solid green;margin: 10px;display: flex;}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

**Edit**

```
//if remainder is 0 then we have completed 4 elements so close the parent
//if we have reached the last element in the array then close the parent
  if (i % 4 === 0 || i === x.length) 
    html += '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```js
var x = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"]
var html = '';
var i=0;
while(i < x.length){
  if (i % 3 === 0) {
    html += '<div class="parent">';
  }
  html += '<div class="child">' + x[i] + '</div>'
  i++;
  if (i % 3 === 0 || i === (x.length - 1)) {
    html += '</div>';
  }
}
if(i%3 !== 0){
    html += '</div>';
}

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = html
```

```css
.child{ margin: 10px; background: green; float: left; padding: 20px}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Why? What did you do? Why did you do it? Code dumps are not *useful* answers.

Comment: @arash the last child should also comes in under parent

Comment: now the answer is correct, latest child has parent :)

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array in groups of `n` fairly easily, using a `for` loop and `slice`:

```js
var x = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"];
var html = "";
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i += 4) {
  html +=
    '<div class="parent">' +
    x.slice(i, i + 4).reduce(function(h, child) {
      return h + '<div class="child">' + child + '</div>';
    }, "") +
    '</div>';
}
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = html;
```

```css
.child{ margin: 10px; background: green; padding: 20px}
.parent {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

*(I've removed the `float` from the CSS and added a parent border, just to make it obvious where the children are.)*

Note that `slice(i, i + 4)` will work even at the end when there aren't four left.

(The `reduce` is just one way to combine all those children into one string.)

Answer (score 1):

Using `splice`, you can get array of 4 elements, loop them and wrap them under the `parent`. `splice` helps you chunk the big array into number of smaller arrays:

```js
var x = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"];
var html = '';
while (x.length > 0) {
  chunk = x.splice(0, 4)
  html += '<div class="parent">';
  for (var i = 0; i < chunk.length; i++) {
    html += '<div class="child">' + chunk[i] + '</div>'
  }
  html += '</div>';
}
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = html
```

```css
.child {
  margin: 10px;
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
}

.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change `if (i % 3 !== 0 || i === (x.length - 1)) {` to `if (i % 3 === (3-1) || i === (x.length - 1)) {` to resolve it by your idea

```js
var x = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"]
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if (i % 3 === 0) {
    html += '<div class="parent">';
  }
  html += '<div class="child">' + x[i] + '</div>'

  if (i % 3 === (3-1) || i === (x.length - 1)) {
    html += '</div>';
  }

}

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = html
```

```css
.child{ margin: 10px; background: green; float: left; padding: 20px}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```